# displaying <li> horizontally with lesscss

Tags: css, less

http://lesscss.org/

I am having the same issue. I changed the display to inline, but doesn't seem to work. Could anyone please tell me as to what I am doing wrong?

```
                        ul{
            width:100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;

            li{
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            display: inline;
            white-space: nowrap;

                a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    letter-spacing: -1px;
                    color: @darkGrey;
                    padding-right: 6px;

                    &:hover{
                        color: @mainColor;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `&:hover` -- Can you _do that_??

Comment: Are you using something other than standard css?

Comment: are u using less css? should u do display: block instead?

Comment: it is hard for us to help if you dont provide necessary info. please put your html markup and compiled css in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

**These 2 comments apply to both LESS CSS or regular CSS**

1. You can't declare `a:hover` until you declare `a:link` and `a:visited`.
2. You don't need both `display:inline` and `float:left`. Float is applying to block level elements, but with display:inline, you are making the `<li>` an inline element.

Comment: I tried with display:block and float:left, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using LESS CSS or alike.

Try display block instead of inline.

```
li{
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: I did and it does not work.The <li>s are displaying vertically, just in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

original answer deleted due to disambiguation over css/less-css but I decided to leave the questions due to some good comments.

Comment: what about the `@darkGrey` colors?

Comment: i've seen stuff like that before being parsed by some other client side something or rather. So I decided not to touch that in case it is referencing something.

Comment: i think he is using LESS CSS. @darkGrey is variable. he didnt show all complete code

Comment: "the & combinator—it’s used when you want a nested selector to be concatenated to its parent selector" - http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

---

Demo : http://plugins.amiwithyou.com/lesscss/demo.htm

---

As per the documentation, you need to
Link your .less stylesheets with the rel set to “stylesheet/less”:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
```

Then download less.js from the top of the page, and include it in the  element of your page, like so:

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.

And then add the following in your styles.less file

```
 @darkGrey:#777;
 @mainColor:#333;
 ul{             
     width:100%;             
     padding: 0;             
     margin: 0;              
     li{             
         list-style-type: none;             
         padding-left: 10px;             
         display: inline;             
         white-space: nowrap;                  
             a{                     
             text-decoration: none;                     
             font-size: 16px;                     
             letter-spacing: -1px;                     
             color: @darkGrey;                     
             padding-right: 6px;                      
                &:hover{                         
                 color: @mainColor;                     
                }                 
            }             
        }
}
```

Please note that,

- I have removed float:left

and

- added "}" at the end

Comment: @user1385685: In my case, it is working. Do you get any error?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's just that the li does not display horizontally. It gets stacked vertically. Test it in IE7 or IE8...Firefox,Chrome it works beautifully.

Comment: I have tested and it worked. As I did it in local, if possible I will share you the link.

Comment: @user1385685: I have added a working demo: http://plugins.amiwithyou.com/lesscss/demo.htm